# weird reputation increments while editing posts

Tags: support, bug, reputation, edits

Nowadays I'm editing posts under [SO](http://s.tk/so). But today, there's something happened comes me weird: I gave an answer that goes 2 upvote (equals +20). I've also edited some posts. But each accepted edits returns to me as +4, instead of +2. Then it goes default value(+2) by -2 from +4.

In addition, I'm very very far from reputation cap!

Comment: Hmm, yeah, [this seems a bit weird](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15512871/revisions).

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to have more than one "necessary" tag at once..

Comment: Sorry @Seth, I'm not used to be here.

Comment: @ekremkrc That's totally fine.  Everyone was new at some point :)

Comment: @Seth Actually it is encouraged to have more than one necessary tag if it describes the question accurately.

Comment: @Doorknob Oh, OK.  Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a small bug in the system.  Looks like your edit got submitted/approved twice somehow:

[image]

I only see one instance of this though..  So it seems like the system eventually sorts itself out.

You might want to retag this with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) instead of [support](/questions/tagged/support).